# OpenShift Route Certificate auto renew

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We have several services running in OpenShift Cluster. Each service is exposed with a route.

For each route we are creating a SSL Certificate. Problem is around managing Certificate expiry for these many routes

One way to solve this problem is to update the Cluster level cert with WildCard domain entries. We do not want to do this as this could be a security risk. Will end up using this approach if no other solution is found.

What are other ways to Manage these many certificates for all the services

How can we auto renew several certificates, any best practice around this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io) to manage certificate generation and renewal. To get cert-manager to inter-operate with OpenShift routes, you need to create [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resources that reference the generated certificates; OpenShift will transform these into appropriate Route resources.

I recently put together a demonstration of this that you can find [here](https://github.com/larsks/cert-manager-routes-demo/blob/main/README.md). See the link for complete details, but essentially we create an Ingress resource like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-server
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: demo-issuer
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - demo-server.example.com
    secretName: demo-server-certificate
  rules:
  - host: demo-server.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: demo-server
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

Cert-manager see the `cert-manager.io/issuer` annotation, generates a certificate in the Secret named by `spec.tls.0.secretName`, and then OpenShift generates a Route in which the certificate is embedded.

Note that while we're using cert-manager with LetsEncrypt, that's not a requirement; cert-manager supports a number of issuers.

Cert-manager will take care of renewing these certificates automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems a good thing to try, but since this uses HTTP-01 Challenge our Docker file has reference to proxy which is on Port-80, will this cause any problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what configuration is implied by your previous comment. I guess try it and see if it works? If it's an option you can use a DNS-01 challenge instead.